# Linked List only working with 1st linked list

Tags: java

So I am trying to view all data in the Linkedlist in java.
They Look like this:

```
private List <Customer> customers;
public databse(){
customers.add(new Customer(101, "Allen", 10))
customers.add (new Customer(102, "John", 15))
customers.add (new Customer(103, "Lucy", 23))
}
```

Then i am trying to view the customer based on th id by using this

```
   private void customer(){
   System.out.println(" ");
   System.out.print("Enter a customer ID: ");
   int id = In.nextInt();
   for(Customer customer:customers )
   {
        if(customer.getID() == id){
            System.out.println(customer.toString());
            System.out.println(" ");
           // break;
          }
          else 
        {System.out.println("That customer does not exist.");
        System.out.println(" ");

        }
        System.out.println(" ");
     break;           
   }
```

Then i get this as an output:

```
Enter a customer ID: 101
101 Allen   10
```

However, if I try to view 102 or 103 it doesn't work

```
Enter a customer ID: 102 
That customer does not exist.
```

What might be the problem? Allen and Customers classes are already called.

Comment: I suggest that either it is a problem with your scanner, or you didn't really add customers 102 and 103.

Comment: it is customers.add sorry i made a mistake in this one. The code still gives the same output

Comment: You've a conditionless `break` statement in the loop body, so the for loop executes only once. Also, remove the statements in the `else` part to avoid repeated "does not exist" message.

Comment: @Samrat show us the complete flow of your program. how you assign values & how you call the search method

Comment: @vishal-wadhwa Thanks alot. It is compiling now.

Comment: The conditionless `break` might be the problem as mentioned by @vishal-wadhwa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did a break at the end of the for, handling only the first customer.
Handle the result *after* the loop.

```
Optional<Customer> foundCustomer = Optional.empty();
for (Customer customer : customers) {
    if (customer.getID() == id) {
        foundCustomer = Optional.of(customer);
        break;
    }
}
```

Or

```
Optional<Customer> foundCustomer = customers.stream().findAny(c -> c.getID() == id);
```

and then

```
if (foundCustomer.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println(foundCustomer.get());
} else {
    System.out.println("That customer does not exist.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your loop where you check the first element and then either print it or `breakout of the loop. The rest of your items are never checked.

Instead you should keep track of if an object was found or not.

```
private void customer(){
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("Enter a customer ID: ");
    int id = In.nextInt();
    boolean found = false;
    for(Customer customer:customers ) {
        if(customer.getID() == id){
            System.out.println(customer.toString());
            System.out.println(" ");
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        System.out.println("That customer does not exist.");
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```